# bode plot in J (right half plane zero, second order)

Tags: j, wolframalpha

While working on Exercise 6.5 of [Ch06](http://www.rdmiddlebrook.com/D_OA_Rules&Tools/Ch%2006.Products%20&%20Sums%20of%20Factored%20P-Z%20Expressions.pdf) in Dr. Middlebrook's D-OA method, I tried to make bode plot of the transfer function:

bodeplot[s/100+100/s*(1+10/s)] (input to wolframalpha)

in J

[image: results from wolframalpha]

Somehow the J code phase plot doesn't agree with Mathematica's result, though the magnitude plot matches fine.

Anything wrong with my J code?

```
Af =: 4 : 0"_ 0
s=.0j1*y
'w q'=.x
f=.(s%w) + (w%s)*(1+w%q*s)
20*10^. | f
)

Pf =: 4 : 0"_ 0
s=.0j1*y
'w q'=.x
f=.(s%w) + (w%s)*(1+w%q*s)
(180%o.1)* 1{ *. f
)

load 'plot'

plot (; (100 10 Af (10 ^ ]))) 0.02*i.200

plot (; (100 10 Pf (10 ^ ]))) 0.02*i.200
```

[image]

To be more general, say a complex variable on the unit circle in the complex plane
z = cos x + I sin x

If we plot its phase angle, there will be a jump at 180 degree (from 180 to -180)

```
z_unit_circle =. ((2 o. ]) + (0j1 * (1 o.]))) @ (180 %~ o.)

plot (180%o.1)*1{"1 *. z_unit_circle i.360
```

[image: unit circle phase angle]

I think that's what happens when phase angle goes around 180 or -180 in the earlier J bode plot.

To avoid this jump, we can make use of the relationship Tan(Im(z)/Re(z)) = Tan(-180 + Im(z)/Re(z)), i.e. to turn -180 before hand.

```
phase_angle =. _180 + (180 % o.1) * (_3 o. %~/) @ +.

Pf =: 4 : 0"_ 0
s=.0j1*y
'w q'=.x
f=.(s%w) + (w%s)*(1+w%q*s)
phase_angle f
)

plot (; (100 10 Pf (10 ^ ]))) 0.02*i.200
```

This is essentially the same as the answer provided by Eelvex.

However this phase_angle[z] has more jumps than Arg[z]

```
plot phase_angle"1 z_unit_circle i.360
```

[image: third quadrant]

So my question is how to make the correct bode plot in J. In other words, knowing the phase angle goes from 3rd quadrant into 2nd quadrant, thus -180 before hand

Answer (score 1):

```
Don't use Arg (*.), use -180 + arctan(Im(T)/Re(T))

 plot  180-~(180%o.1) *  _3 o. %~/"1  +. T 0j1 * (10 ^  3-~0.1*i.80)
```

[image]

*(where T is your transfer function: `T =: 3 : '(y%100) + (100*(1+10%y))%y'`)*